# Issue in setting up Godaddy emails on Magento

Tags: magento2, order-email

We have recently migrated our email server to Godaddy and transactional emails have stopped working from Magento. We have tried all options but of no help. Our customers have stopped getting emails related to order confirmation etc.

Comment: Have you configured cron on the new server?

Comment: contact your server provider

Comment: Nikunj, do you mean configuration of cron on Magento or Godaddy?